# How to use indices in OpenSearch Dashboard?

Tags: opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I have installed and running OpenSearch and OpenSearch Dashboards using docker containers in Windows 11. Both OpenSearch and Opensearch Dashboard are running. I can access the OpenSearch dasboard from the web browser.

I have ingested some data into the OpenSearch server, through Data-Prepper pipeline. I can see the Index in the OpenSearch server and I can see the same index under OpenSearch Dasboard. Since I am very new to OpenSearch Dashboard, I do not know how to use this index for Visualization of data contained in the index.

I have gone through many videos and OpenSearch documentation, but it is not very clear on how to use the index for searching or visualizing the data.